# Why is there no reaction after I click the collapse toggle button?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap 4 to set up a navbar. I don't know why there is no reaction after I click the collapse toggle button. Is there some mistakes inside?

P.S. I am using the codepen.io to write this code, but I don't think this is the problem.

```
<div>
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light" style="background: coral">
   <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav-content" aria-controls="nav-content" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Wenhu's home</a>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="nav-content">
    <nav class="navbar-nav">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Who am I</a>
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Past</a>
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Now</a>
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Future</a>
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact me</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
</nav>
</div>
```

Comment: send Your Code pen link

Comment: Check My Ans .. In Snippet ,,,

Comment: Pen Settings .. Are left hand side.. Where HTML Written .. Check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script async src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script async src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded " style="background: coral">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" style="background: coral">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Wenhu's home</a>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Who am I</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Past</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Now</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Future</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact me</a>
      </li>
     
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I works now, but I am still a little confused that I have added the jquery and bootstrap in codepen settings, why do I still need those lines of declaration?  I have commented out the first few lines of <link> and <script>, it come back ineffective again.

Comment: I have also checked the codepen link you sent me, there is no declaration of script and link or sth. However, it works well, ...sad

Comment: hellow.. @WenhuCao

Comment: Click On setting Symbol of... Left hand Side of HTML .. in Codepen

Comment: Yeah, I have noticed that. While I chose https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css in CSS, then I chose https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/js/bootstrap.min.js and https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js in Javascript. I found the button could work, but after I toggle it open, it will automatically close......

Answer (score -1):

You must include the jquery and javascript in `<script>` tag at the end of the `<body>`
like this

```
<body>
    <div>
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light" style="background: coral">
   <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav-content" aria-controls="nav-content" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Wenhu's home</a>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end">
    <nav class="navbar-nav" id="nav-content">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Who am I</a>
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Past</a>
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Now</a>
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Future</a>
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact me</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
</nav>
</div>


<!--here. replace with your bootstrap version-->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- end -->
 </body>
```